# Capture query param and insert into to form field

Tags: plugins, urls, parameter

We use WordPress for our landing pages. We have a query param `?utm_source=some_string` that we'd like to capture (or pass along as user navigates site) and then eventually append to URL when user clicks a Sign Up link (visible on all the WP pages).

I'm not a WordPress wiz but this seems like it should be pretty straight forward. Maybe store in a cookie or session variable?

Thoughts?

Comment: this can't be hard!?!